# how to get DB backup script from Remote Server in MySQL using command-line utility?

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, database-scripts

Can anybody tell me that how to get DB backup script from Remote Server in MySQL using command-line utility?

I'm using a command as follows, but not working:

```
C:\>mysqldump -h <server ip> -u <user-id> -p <password> <db name> >
 E:\dumpfilename.sql
```

Comment: what do you mean under "DB backup script"? Db dump?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @JeffreyVandenborne mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user '<user-id>'@'%' to database
'<password>' when selecting the database

Comment: Do you mean to take dump for entire database or a particular table?

Comment: @ShreekumarS, edited my post. Take a look now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for the password is wrong. You need to write the password immediately after the `-p`, without a space. That's why the password is interpreted as the database name.

Write this instead:

```
C:\>mysqldump -h <server ip> -u <user-id> -p<password> <db name> >
 E:\dumpfilename.sql
```

Notice how there is no space after `-p`. An example would be `-phunter2`, where the password is "hunter2".

Comment: I tried as follows 

`C:\>mysqldump -h 111.111.111.111 -u userid -pMyPassword DBname > E:\dumpfilename.sql` but not working

Comment: Again, what is your error message? Just stating that it isn't working isn't helpful.