# Automate Putty To Do Daily Task

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, putty

I am fairly new to `putty`, need your help guys I would repeatedly connect to a linux server using putty almost everyday then connect to one more linux sever from within previous linux server as it contains database, then login to `mysql` and take a database back up

I want to automate this process by creating a bat file as am on windows 7, i was able to login to putty and then to mysql, but console disappears after that

1. login to putty with username password
2. ssh to another server and login with username password
3. login to mysql then take a db back up using mysql dump
4. copy the db backup file to desktop

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When your goal is making the backup, you do not need to automate Putty. You can make a unix script that will call mysql and make a backup. When that script works, you can add it to `crontab` (Unix scheduler), so it will run every day.
You need some more testing before crontab works well: your environment in an interactiv session will be different.

Edit: Did not answer the last part:
And `4. copy the db backup file to desktop`

There are different ways for transporting the backup. You can have a mounted drive, shared directory, or use some transport protocol like `rsync` or `scp`. I can not tell which fits best in your situation.

Comment: How would a Unix script download the backup file and put it on the Windows desktop?

Comment: Isn't `putty` an interactive command? And why do you have to hop from one server to another?

Comment: the db and the application has their own servers due to this any interaction with the db i need to first login to application server and from that access the db server

Comment: Thanks Walter for your reply, but am using a windows pc at work place so writing unix scripts is out of the question, if you have any other alternatives  please do suggest thanks

Comment: Share a folder on your Windows PC (better: some shared windows server), and make a backup from windows. I never did this myself, but perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/10847184/3220113 helps.
Use Windows task manager for a daily task.